# Dismiss a select2 multiselect dropdown when it loses focus?

Tags: jquery-select2

I would like the dropdown that appears when the select2 box is in "multiselect" mode to disappear when the user clicks into another field on the page, clicks a button on the page, etc.  It remains visible even if the user clicks a button to launch a dialog.

Using version 3.5.

Comment: Are you sure you are using 3.5? It should be using a mask that should completely block any clicks outside of the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin!  I found the mask - I didn't realize there was supposed to be one - its height and width were set to 0, for some reason.  It might be because this dropdown was itself in a popup dialog?  I was able to address it in CSS with height: 100%; width: 100%; on the select2-drop-mask class.  Your comment got me unstuck.  Thank you!